# Is this video a scam? I want to get into flashloans

Tags: etherscan, flash-loans, scam

Can anyone confirm if this video is a scam or if the code he uses will actually work?

I want to get into Flashloans so if anyone can provide good resources for learn that would be great!

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6RT3I4aaFE`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**It is a full-blown scam!**

I didn't even look at the code, but probably even won't need to. There are so many irregularities in the linked video.

Remix is saying, the scripts are deploying to the ropsten test chain, but metamask is popping up with mainnet setting.

Also right at the top of the script, it says in the comment that it's not meant to be used on ethereum mainnet and won't work on it.

This guy also created the script in the root folder of the project, not in the designated `contracts` folder. It will compile and everything, but things like this really tell me how much he really understands about what he's doing.

Now looking at the code itself:

On the top, a lot of imports that aren't actually used.
One import from IPFS conviniently called `CodeManager` is used to do all of the actions... weird

Look at this piece of code

```
// Perform tasks (clubbed all functions into one to reduce external calls & SAVE GAS FEE)
manager.performTasks();
```

It claims it does a lot of useful stuff so let's look into the imported manager code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Manager {

    function performTasks() public pure{
    }

    function pancakeswapDepositAddress() public pure returns (address) {
        return 0x153c9e7fae80771025d5C01851073F7Df5ceceF0;
    }
}
```

It does literally **NOTHING** that surely saves a lot of gas.

Also there's a second function claiming to return `pancakeSwapDepositAddress`
Why wouldn't you copy the address into the previous contract, this call isn't very effective in terms of gas.. unless you don't want to hide it so it's not visible on the first glance.

This is the attackers account on etherscan.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x153c9e7fae80771025d5C01851073F7Df5ceceF0

**Never, ever deploy that contract and send any ether into it.**

Also never trust people claiming they can help you getting high profits.

Please, if you want to get into ethereum, learn about how the system works, learn Solidity so you're able to do the same analysis I just did.

As a rule of thumb, never put any ethereum into project's code that either you completely understand or it has been audited by an established organization.

Answer (score 0):

Video removed from Youtube. i didn't watched it. but beaware of these kind of scams. if you have any issue or any doubt you can ask